# flex container inside position absolute container not follow parent dimension

Tags: html, css

I try to create modal box that 2 type design, my problem flex that inside absolute parent not follow parent dimension. if u see image inside flex container, it not fill all space. but the scroll appear.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal')
modal.style.width = `${screen.width}px`;
modal.style.height = `${screen.height}px`;
```

```css
.container { width: 100% }

#modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001 !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#modal > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#modal > div > div {
    background-color: bisque;
}

#modal > div > div > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="modal">
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vGuQeQsoRgU/maxresdefault.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You setting modal width bigger than your screenview by scripts, it can be done by CSS, see:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  /* to make child element use parent dimentions, it have to be "relative" */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px; /* set max container width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center align of container */
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

/* use media queries to set you container max width size for larger screens */
@media (min-width: 1680px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  /* minimal modal height will take 70% of screen height */
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
}

.modal-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.image {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Quisque ut nisi. Morbi ac felis.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-inner">
      <h2>Ut a nisl id ante</h2>
      <p>Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Praesent turpis. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>
      <img class="image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vGuQeQsoRgU/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still there's scroll both side.

Comment: u just remove overflow scroll. u not solve. modal container should fix size follow screen size. but nested modal fill that till fix screen size and if larger than modal container size, it show scroll.

Comment: i just want to know if flex bug, exactly i can solve it with javascript. but i just want to know this wrong behavior from flex or misunderstanding of me about flex container that i missing.

Comment: @johnwick I'm not sure I can get you correctly. Are you expecting to work this modal with breakpoints or what? Can you provide expected results?

Comment: @johnwick I think you need to update your post with what you're trying to achieve because so far, nobody understands. Your JS is telling the modal to expand to the height and width of the screen which the above answer does (click "expand snippet") but why would you need a flexbox to begin with? Flex boxes are for laying out content but you don't need a flexbox for one item. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ And why would you want a modal to expand the entire screen and then leave the user hanging with a modal they can't close or hide?

Comment: @YaroslavTrach i wrong, i think this flex behaviour. but overflow scroll. how to make scroll only appear if child greater than parent dimension without javascript? its impossible?

Comment: @YaroslavTrach from official firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow. if content greater than container. overflow run. but in my example. content not greater than parent dimension. but the overflow run?

Comment: @johnwick Ok, I see. I've updated my answer, I've provided you two containers, first contain regular text, second one - contain modal window. Also, container now has breakpoints for different screens; To see how this modal works with content, larger it's viewport you can run Code snippet and expand it on full screen and compare. Moreover, on fullscreen mode you can resize screen and check if it's what you expected. Let me know about results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover;` to fit image in the screen.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal')
modal.style.width = `${screen.width}px`;
modal.style.height = `${screen.height}px`;
```

```css
.container { 
width: max-content;
height:max-content;
overflow:hidden;
}

#modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001 !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="modal">
       <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vGuQeQsoRgU/maxresdefault.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still theres scroll, and u show example in wrong code. u should show example if content smaller from modal, it doesn;t show scroll, if bigger, it shows scroll.